# Find the asymptotic expansion as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}}\right\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, divisor-sum, sums-of-squares, fractional-part

This expression comes from the asymptotic expansion of

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}}\right\rfloor - k} \tau \left({i \left({2\, k + i}\right)}\right)$$

From Adrian W. Dudek, "Note on the number of divisors of reducible quadratic polynomials", arXiv:1806.01404v1 [math.NT] 4 Jun 2018.  Here $\tau \left({x}\right)$ us the number of divisors of $x$ and $\left\{{x}\right\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Now assuming that $\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}$ is distributed uniformly we can write assuming that $\left\{{x}\right\} = 1/2$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$

$$S \left({N}\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\} \sim \frac{1}{4} N$$

The following numerical tests are observed

$$\begin{array}{ccc} N & S \left({N}\right) & N/4 - S \left({N}\right) \\ {10}^{4} & 2,470.1789390926911658 & 29.8210609073088342 \\ {10}^{5} & 24,907.909459652367788 & 92.090540347632212 \\ {10}^{6} & 249,660.30707854707527 & 339.69292145292473 \\ {10}^{7} & 2,498,926.5245972764825 & 1,073.4754027235175 \\ {10}^{8} & 24,996,910.832762803688 & 3,089.167237196312 \end{array}$$

which indicates that the actual expansion is

$$S \left({N}\right) \sim \frac{1}{4} N - \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{N} + \cdots$$

I am looking for a derivation of this result assuming that my approximation it is correct.

Applying the definition of the floor function we get $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\} =
\frac{1}{2}\, \left\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left[{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right] - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1,\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \not\in \mathbb{Z}}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} arctan \left({\cot \left({\pi \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right)}\right)$$  where $\left[{...}\right]$ are Iverson brackets.  Due to the numerous jump disconnectedness we can not apply the Euler-Maclaurin formula to the trigonometric sum.

Plot of the $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} arctan \left({\cot \left({\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}}\right)}\right)$function showing the discontinuities with estimated envelop bands $\pm \sqrt{N}/3$
[image]

I arrived at this formula by using Mathematica Version 12 applied to the definition of the fractional part to obtain the closed form
$$\left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\} =
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin \left({2\, \pi\, n \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right) =
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2\, \pi} \left({\log \left({1 - {e}^{2\, \pi\, i \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}}\right) - \log \left({1 - {e}^{- 2\, \pi\, i \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}}\right)}\right) =
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} arctan \left({\cot\left({\pi \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right)}\right)$$

where $\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ after simplification to real variables.

This is where the problem is derived: $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\rfloor =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}- \sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\}$$

I have used Euler-Maclaurin formula on the second sum of the above equation to get

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}} \sim
\frac{1}{8} \left({\sqrt{5} + 4\, arccsch \left({2}\right)}\right) {N}^{2} +
\frac{1}{4} \left({\sqrt{5} - 2}\right) N 
+ \frac{1}{12 \sqrt{5}}
+ \left({{N}^{- 2}}\right)$$

Which leaves the fractional part sum.  If on the other hand a better solution can be derived from the first sum $\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\rfloor$ that would do just as well.  The first sums looks like it may be a version of Gauss Circle Problem.

Comment: This expression is weird, you need to justify how you came to it, why we'd want to look at thisone and not another one.

Comment: The larger goal is to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}}\right\rfloor$ to reciprocal in $N$ as $N \rightarrow\infty$.  I am just braking the problem up into solvable components.

Comment: Obviously, but this is a weird expression with apparently no arithmetical meaning nor natural apparence, thus  you need to show how you came to it. That somewhere in the paper they say it is useful isn't sufficient.

Comment: The graph you give fluctuates wildly between positive and negative values, so there wouldn't be an asymptotic expression (not a smooth, monotonic one anyway).

Comment: Yes, so I am thinking if I average over one continuous interval would I get a meaningful result?  Also given the wildly fluctuation of the trigonometric sum, what other methods can be applied to obtain some kind of average trend?